# Disable iOS Simulator auto focus when run the app from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Can I disable auto focusing iOS Simulator when the app is run from Xcode? Really annoying that it removes the focus from the editor

Comment: I believe there is a way, but haven't found the answer. It is some setting somewhere, as I have seen some video tutorials where this doesn't happen to the author.

Comment: I was not able to figure this out for XCode but I found an option in AppCode to disable the auto focus. In "Edit Configurations...", select your app. Then select the "Options" tab and uncheck the "Make application active after launch" option. Hope this helps.