# Disable iOS Simulator auto focus when running the app

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm getting this warning on the console all the time:

[console warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47RWp.png)

I figure out that happens when I press any key on my keyboard and the focus is on the Simulator's device.

The problem is that when I run the app on Xcode the focus goes to the Simulator and every key that I type on my keyboard counts as an input to the Simulator's device because the focus is on it. Is there a way to prevent the auto focus on running the app on Xcode?

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887129/disable-ios-simulator-auto-focus-when-run-the-app-from-xcode), but back them there was no answer telling if it's possible to do it on Xcode.